# Variable does not exist: MasterRecordId

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

below is the code

```
trigger efs_ProjectTrigger on Project__c (after delete) 
{
 Set<ID> ProjectIds = new Set<ID>();
   for(Project__c  Proj:trigger.old){
     if(Proj.MasterRecordId!=null)
     ProjectIds.add(CSOPP.id);
     }
     if(!ProjectIds.isEmpty())
     utility.updateProjectsChildOpps(ProjectIds);
    // End 
}
```

when the we are merging the two projects , we will get `masterrecordid` but  i am getting Variable does not exist: `MasterRecordId` in trigger.

Comment: Isn't `merge` only supported on a few custom objects (`Lead`/`Contact`/`Account`)? What leads you to believe you can merge `Project__c` records?

Comment: we are using DupEliminator(App Exchange product) to merge the Project__c records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MasterRecordId only exists on Account, Contact, Case, and Lead. Other objects cannot be merged using the DML merge operation. If there is a merge feature for your object, it's a custom feature written in code. You'll need to check your other code to see how it was accomplished.

Comment: And [Case](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm?q=case) - as of API version 49.0, I believe.

Comment: @BrentBowers I'm pretty sure the API version is correct. Either way, it exists now, so I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!